# Why does Tor Browser disable Javascript optimizations?

Tags: javascript, anonymity, tor, fingerprinting

The security level slider in Tor Browser disables various Javascript optimizations.

How can the presence or absence of optimizations be a browser tracking method?

Answer (score 3):

The presence of certain JavaScript features can be used to fingerprint the person like

> "X's unique hash is ...".

Whereas the absence of certain JavaScript features can be used to fingerprint the person like

> "has disabled X".

It's not recommended to tweak the Tor Browser Bundle in any way, as **a lot** of people use it (with default settings) and therefore your fingerprint only says "uses Tor Browser Bundle".

---

Browser fingerprinting resources:

- [privacytools.io](https://www.privacytools.io/#fingerprint)
- [my blog post](https://shifterovich.github.io/post.html#0)